# How can I use join in SQL to delete record?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, mariadb

I hava a problem with my program I'm trying to delete a record from a table using a join with Java this is my code:

```
try{
            String sql ="DELETE f FROM facture f INNER JOIN client c ON f.idClient=c.id WHERE c.nom= ? ORDER BY idFact DESC LIMIT 1";
            PreparedStatement pr = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pr.setString(1,nom);
            pr.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("supprimer");
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and this is the error :

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY idFact DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL/MariaDB you have a choice:

- You can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` and the `FROM` can only refer to one table.
- You can have a `FROM` that refers to multiple tables.

The solution?  Rephrase the query:

```
DELETE FROM facture f 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM client c 
                  WHERE f.idClient = c.id AND c.nom = ? 
                 )
    ORDER BY f.idFact DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Or you can use a subquery to get the row to delete:

```
DELETE f
    FROM facture f JOIN
         (SELECT f.idFact
          FROM facture f JOIN
               client c
               ON f.idClient = c.id AND c.nom = ?
          ORDER BY f.idFact DESC
          LIMIT 1
         ) ff
         ON ff.idFact = f.idFact
```